# How to create a model for csv data set and to calculate predicted result using TensorFlow JS

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow.js

I am new to TensorFlow JS.
I followed the TensorFlow JS documentation to create model and train it to calculate predicted result from the created model.

But I don't know how to train the created model for CSV file and calculate predicted result for two or more column in the CSV file.

Could anybody guide me with a sample for creating, training model with CSV file and to calculate the predicted result?

```
const csvUrl = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-examples/multivariate-linear-regression/data/boston-housing-train.csv';

function save(model) {
    return model.save('downloads://boston_model');
}

function load() {
    return tf.loadModel('indexeddb://boston_model');
}

async function run() {
  // We want to predict the column "medv", which represents a median value of a
  // home (in $1000s), so we mark it as a label.
  const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
    csvUrl, {
      columnConfigs: {
        medv: {
          isLabel: true
        }
      }
    });
  // Number of features is the number of column names minus one for the label
  // column.
  const numOfFeatures = (await csvDataset.columnNames()).length - 1;

  // Prepare the Dataset for training.
  const flattenedDataset =
    csvDataset
    .map(([rawFeatures, rawLabel]) =>
      // Convert rows from object form (keyed by column name) to array form.
      [Object.values(rawFeatures), Object.values(rawLabel)])
    .batch(10);

  // Define the model.
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [numOfFeatures],
    units: 1
  }));
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.000001),
    loss: 'meanSquaredError'
  });

  // Fit the model using the prepared Dataset
  model.fitDataset(flattenedDataset, {
    epochs: 10,
    callbacks: {
      onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
        console.log(epoch, logs.loss);
      }
    }
  });

  const savedModel=save(model);
}

run().then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

Comment: Do you want to use a single model to predict the two or more columns, or use one model to predict each of the columns?

Comment: @scai could you please share me both so that it help me to learn more

Answer (score 0):

Using [tf.data.csv](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.15.1/#data.csv) you can train a model with a csv file.

However the browser cannot directly read a file. Thus, you have to serve the csv file on a local server

**Update**

Your model uses only a single perceptron. Using multiple perceptrons can help improving the accuracy of the model, ie adding multiple layers. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/boston-housing/index.js) as how it is done.

Comment: I tried this solution already but the predicted result which i got from trained model is so mush different from original value, from the trained model by referring the below link I think some thing I had missed.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-data
It will be very useful if you share a sample code snippet with sample model for calculating predicted result regarding this

Comment: It will be easier to add a code snippet if you add in your question the relevant part of your GitHub code to demonstrate what you have done do far. You can edit your question.

Comment: Please find the code snippet from this link. https://codepen.io/kinchi/pen/JxqjaM?editors=1111. It would be very helpful if you make the necessary changes to calculate predicted result for a given column